# PHP Dynamic Inclusion issue "Undefined Index" when redirecting users

Tags: php, html

Okay so I have a simple script that is supposed to route traffic on my site however, I am have a hard time figuring out how to fix the "Undefined Index Error" that appears at the top of the page when ever I use the URL "localhost/sitename/"

```
if(isset($_GET['p'])){ $notify = $_GET['p']; }
if ($page == "home"){
    include(__DIR__.'/_includes/pages/home.php');
} elseif($page == "maintenance") {
    include(__DIR__.'/_includes/pages/maintenance.php');
} else {
    include(__DIR__.'/_includes/pages/home.php');
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong in regards towards this? Now the question was flagged, but I simply trying to redirect users to the home page even if they just type localhost/site name. And I still get the following error: Notice: Undefined index: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\BayingHound\index.php on line 3

Comment: While it may seem so, it's not necessarily helping to explain my issue.

Comment: I know this may seem like a Duplicate question but I am trying to fix this.

Comment: "Undefined index *what of what*" exactly? On which line? With what code?

Comment: @deceze Notice: Undefined index: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\BayingHound\index.php on line 3

Comment: So the first line of your code above is triggering this? That should be impossible with the given code. The only explanation would be that `'p'` is not `'p'` because of some hidden characters or something.

Comment: @deceze It only happens when I use the url localhost/sitename/

Comment: Are you sure the same file is being run in that case?

Comment: It should be trying to run index.php

Comment: Confirm that. Put a big `echo 'HEEEELLOOOO';` at the top of the file you expect to be running. Is the file you're showing above surely C:\xampp\htdocs\BayingHound\index.php?

Comment: Okay, so the file home.php is working fine, but my issue is that when I try the URL localhost/sitename/ it redirects to the page I want but still displays  the error

Comment: So what exactly is on C:\xampp\htdocs\BayingHound\index.php on line 3? Can you confirm that it is the `$_GET` related line above?

Comment: @deceze The following is on line 3: $page = $_GET['p'];

Comment: So, different file/code from the one above? And no `isset`? Have you read and *understood* all the duplicates?

Comment: Nevermind the issue has been resolved for now.